# populating select menu with codeigniter and php

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, menu, populate

Hello I am a beginner in codeigniter framework and I have a problem!

There is a table that needs to be populated with all sorts of data, and one of items will be select menu with options, and while I am trying to populate that select menu I'm stuck and now I have a problem.

When I call controller's method my_courses():

```
 function my_courses(){

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); //1 username from session 

    $this->load->model('model_professor'); //2 we load a model,whose task is to load professors courses from table

    $result =$this->model_professor->professors_classes($username); //3 so we send username to that model 

    if($result == false){ 
        echo "Professor has no courses ";
    }else{ //4 model will return results collected from table 
        $query = $this->model_professor->professors_classes($username);
        $data['records'] = $query;

        //
        //
    //WE SEND DATA TO A TEST PAGE AND THIS IS OK!!! WHEN I DO THAT EVERYTHING WORKS FINE
        //
        //

        $this->load->view('professor/test',$data);
    }       
}
```

MODEL professors_classes:

```
function professors_classes($username){
    $this->db->where("username", $username); 

    $query = $this->db->get("table_teach_a_course");  
    //if we have results then we will return them 
    if($query->result()){
        return $query->result();
    }
    //else we return false
    else{
        return false;
    }           
}
```

This is my stripped test page without name and value in select and in option, and here everything works fine. Here I manage to catch results and to show them:

```
    <?php if(isset($records)) { ?>

        <select>

    <?php foreach ($records as $row){ ?>
        <option value=""> <?php echo $row->sifra_predmeta; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>

        </select>

    <?php } ?>
```

But problem occures when in my controller I send data to other page(view) that actually is important to me.
So when I do this in method my_courses():

```
$this->load->view('professor/professor_view_insert_labwork',$data);
```

I think that this should send data to my view: professor_view_insert_labwork, but I cannot get to that data on that view. I just don't know how and why!

This is my stripped but "IMPORTANT" view,again without name and value in select and in option, the professor_view_insert_labwork view:

```
<?php
echo form_open("controller_professor/insert_labwork"); 
?>
        <table border="1">

            <tr> 
                <td>course name</td> <td>button</td> <td></td>  
            </tr> 

            <tr>
                <td>                        
                    <?php if(isset($records)) { ?>
                        <select>
                            <?php foreach ($records as $row){ ?>
                                <option value=""> <?php echo $row->sifra_predmeta; ?> </option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                     <?php
                    }else { 
                        echo"<h2>No records were returned!</h2>";
                    } ?> 
                </td> 


                <td> 
                    <input type="submit" class="" value="Save" /> 
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
<?php 
echo form_close(); 
?>
```

but it constantly ejects in the else loop and echo out message No records were returned!

I do not know why in this view - professor_view_insert_labwork, I can not get up to data $records, but in test view I manage to pull out the data.

Please help me because I really do not know what was wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

Change model

```
function professors_classes($username)
{
    $this->db->where("username", $username);

    $query = $this->db->get("table_teach_a_course");
    //if we have results then we will return them
    $result = $query->result_array();  //here
    if(!empty($result))
    {            
        return $result; //here

    }
    //else we return false
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And controller

```
<?

    function my_courses(){

        $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); //1 username from session

        $this->load->model('model_professor'); //2 we load a model,whose task is to load professors courses from table

        $result =$this->model_professor->professors_classes($username); //3 so we send username to that model

        if($result == false)
        {
            echo "Professor has no courses ";
        }
        else
        {
            $data['records'] = $this->model_professor->professors_classes($username);
            $this->load->view('professor/test',$data);//make sure your page is correct
        }
    }

?>
```

In view

```
<?php if(!empty($records))
{
    ?>
    <select>

        <?php
            foreach ($records as $row)
            {
                ?>
                <option value=""> <?php echo $row['sifra_predmeta'] ?> </option>
            <?php
            }
        ?>

    </select>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: now throws an error in the model for this line: $ result = $ query> result_array ();

But I still do not understand. Overall I managed to nicely fill drop-down menu, and now I try to just copy my test page in the professor_view_insert_labwork page, and when I do that he again goes in the else loop, and this is the part that i do not understand. I just copy paste my test page into professor_view_insert_labwork page and change in controler: $this->load->view('professor/professor_view_insert_labwork',$data); and still nothing!

Comment: there is no space on here `$ result = $ query> result_array ();`

Comment: I made mistake when i post code here , there is no space   in my code

Answer (score 0):

in your model replace

```
if($query->result()){
    return $query->result();
}
```

with

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I tried now but still the same problem.it works the same on the test page, but on my professor view again go to else loop